# PDO and bindParam Issue

Tags: php

Ok, so here is my code ...

```
public function insert_cover($title, $description, $category_id, $filename)
{
    if($this->category_exists($category_id)) {
        $sth = $this->con->prepare('
            INSERT INTO cover
            (id, title, description, image, category_id, timestamp)
            VALUES
            (null, :title, :description, :image, :category_id, null)
        ');

        $sth->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':image', $filename);
        $sth->bindParam('::category_id',  $category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $sth->execute();

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is my error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /MAMP/htdocs/*****/lib/DB.class.php on line 44
```

It works fine if I don't use `bindParam` and add an array of key => value pairs to `execute()`

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Probably a typo in `$sth->bindParam('::category_id',  $category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);`
Correct: `$sth->bindParam(':category_id',  $category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: Stumped by a typo for 20 minutes. It's been a long day. Thank you.

Comment: Been there, done that! :D Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have two colons for `category_id`.